# How best to create, manage, and delete systemd units with Ansible?

Tags: systemd, ansible

Several of our Ansible playbooks and rules install scripts that need to be run regularly, either on a schedule or triggered by changes to files. We can use `systemd` units for this purpose.

We can write our own Ansible code for creating, deleting and managing these units and copy it around wherever needed, but of course it would be nicer to use an existing module that others already maintain.

[The standard systemd module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/systemd_module.html) doesn't support creating or deleting units.
Ansible Galaxy finds several modules that may fit the bill, but frankly it's hard to see the wood for the trees.

if you use Ansible, how do you address this?  Which approach do you recommend?  Are you using a module and if you do, which one and why?

Comment: You have to template out a `.service` file into the right location, then use the `systemd` module with `daemon_reload`. Never used a module for this.

Comment: Since `systemd` service files are structured like INI files, to create service files from scratch the [`ini_file` module – Tweak settings in INI files](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/general/ini_file_module.html) module could be used.  See [in example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75816669/6771046) or [Ansible - Edit a `systemd` service file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72389013/6771046).

Comment: FWIW. See [systemd.yml](https://github.com/vbotka/ansible-linux-postinstall/blob/master/tasks/systemd.yml). [edit] the question and provide [mre](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). I'd like to update the [Example 2: Create units (WIP)](https://ansible-linux-postinstall.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide-tasks/systemd-ex2.html#example-2-create-units-wip).